# Bottom border is missing for first or last site in Stack Exchange All sites list view

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com

In Stack Exchange All sites list view when [Sort by: Oldest](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest), each site having proper bottom border except the last site in the list as per the design.

But when change to [Sort by: Newest](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#newest) in the list view, the first site doesn't have the bottom border and the last site having the bottom border.

After inspecting the element the `border-bottom: none` is set for the `.lv-item:last-child`. But when the **Sort by** is changing from oldest to newest, the last item in the list *(Stack Overflow)* is not consider as last-child. Currently the `last-child` style sticks to **Stack Overflow en español**.

Screen shot for reference:

[image: Bottom border missing on sort by newest]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the `.lv-item:last-child` rule altogether.

The DOM order of the elements doesn't change when one changes the sort order, causing the rule to keep applying to the last element in the DOM, wherever it actually is in the display.